# Simple Javascript for POST HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, fiddler

I am using Fiddler to capture the POST HTTP request from server to my device. 
I want to reuse this request in my web app using a simple Javascript. 
Below is what is capture by Fiddler with Headers and Request Body.

POST http request URL: https://api.graspio.com/v1/iot/deploy

```
token: XXX
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 157
Host: api.graspio.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/3.8.0

{"payload":{"sensors":[],"type":"IFTTT_ACTION_DEPLOY"},"targets":[{"key":"NGU3MWFkZTEtN2U5Yi00YTZmLWI1NzQtZjZkNDk3YTc5YWFj","meta":{"id":"15755082003240"}}]}
```

My code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", 'https://api.graspio.com/v1/iot/deploy', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Token', 'XXX');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', '157');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Host', 'api.graspio.com');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Connection', ' Keep-Alive');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip');
xhr.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'okhttp/3.8.0');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    sensors: '', type: 'IFTTT_ACTION_DEPLOY', key: 'NGU3MWFkZTEtN2U5Yi00YTZmLWI1NzQtZjZkNDk3YTc5YWFj', id: '15755082003240'
}));
```

For some reason I get OPTIONS and Bad gateway, any tips for me?

Answer (score 0):

The OPTIONS request is [CORS pre-flight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request), which is required since you're using a POST method.  It's there to ensure that the origin of your request is allowed to make that request.  Otherwise, random websites could act on behalf of a user.

As for the Bad Gateway error, that's up to your server to handle.

Comment: I see. So in my case, there's no chance that I can avoid OPTIONS request since my http request is not simple. How do I make my POST request get through the server? What can I do to replicate Fiddler in sending this request?

Comment: Your POST request will go through if the server allows it.  The response header minimally needs to indicate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: example.com`, where `example.com` is your origin.  (You can get away with `*` for that value too, for many things.)  There might be additional OPTIONS response headers you need to allow for additional headers on the request/response.